# RXJS Show accumulated result within a timerange

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to make a function that takes in a RXJS stream and return an accumulated result for last x minute (or a given timerange)
I think this is probably easier to explain if I give an example:

I'll try to illustrate what I want with marble diagrams:

```
I want to get the accumulated result for the last minute (60 seconds):


Stream:                  [---a---b---c---a--->
1 min in time:           [-------------------]
Result:  {a:2, b: 1, c:1}

After a couple of ms: 
Stream:                  [---a---b---c---a----a----a>
1 min in time:                  [-------------------]
Result:  {a:3, b: 1, c:1}

After a couple of ms: 
Stream:                  [---a---b---c---a----a----a----a-->
1 min in time:                         [-------------------]
Result:  {a:4, b: 0, c:0}

After a couple of ms: 
Stream:                  [---a---b---c---a----a----a----a---c---c>
1 min in time:                               [-------------------]
Result:  {a:3, b: 0, c:2}

After a couple of ms: 
Stream:                  [---a---b---c---a----a----a----a---c---c-----c-->
1 min in time:                                       [-------------------]
Result:  {a:1, b: 0, c:3}
```

It should emit a new result every time the accumulated result changes. (So when new value comes in to the result or when a old value pops out of the result)

Comment: More than for a function, it seems that you are looking for an Observable that emits every "couple of milliseconds" the accumulated values of the source stream in the last minute. Am I right?

Comment: I want it to emit when the result changes.

Comment: So between your second and third example there should be another notification with result `Result:  {a:3, b: 0, c:1}`, right?

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: The first one should be empty no? All your other observbables return what happened before `[` but your first one doesn't

Comment: When you start the stream it will always empty. And then the result will always contain the accumulated result for the last minute.

Comment: is it manditory to depend on the data coming in like `{a:2, b: 1, c:1}` or is it JUST/ONLY that the accumulated result matters

Comment: I ask because customising the input would be very helpful, and the object `{a:2, b: 1, c:1}` can be `['a','a','b','c']` or `['a','b','a','c']` etc...

Comment: I just wanted the logic map to something and just display the result for the last minute.It was the last part which is important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of every value as having a minute-long lifetime - it "enters" when it's
born, and it "exits" when it's finished.

So each value needs to be converted into an observable modeling the enter/exit
events. Then all you need is a simple reducer to accumulate the events into the
value/count map you want.

Creating a custom operator from this is straightforward. You can parameterize
the "lifetime", and even the reducer that handles the enter/exit actions (tons
of ways to accumulate and de-accumulate).

```js
stream$.pipe(
  mergeMap((value) => {
    const add$ = of({ type: 'ENTER', value });
    const remove$ = of({ type: 'EXIT', value }).pipe(delay(60e3));
    return merge(add$, remove$);
  }),
  scan((state, { type, value }) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'ENTER':
        return { ...state, [value]: (state[value] || 0) + 1 };
      case 'EXIT':
        return { ...state, [value]: state[value] - 1 };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }, {})
);
```

[Here is a stackblitz demonstrating the behavior with keypress events.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ens4h8?file=index.ts)

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks for providing a clear solution in stackblitz! This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, you could try a solution using the `scan` operator with some `map` transformation.

The code could look like this, refer to the comments inline.

```
//  accumulator$ is the Observable that emits the values accumulated in the last minute
// source$ is the source Observable
const accumulator$ = source$.pipe(
  // first thing we add to each element notified by source$ the timestamp of when it is notified
  map((d) => ({ val: d, ts: Date.now() })),
  // then we use the scan operator to emit a new accumulator everytime a new
  // value is received from upstream
  scan((acc, val) => {
    const now = val.ts;
    // only the values which are not older than xxx time, in this case xxx is
    // 1000 milliseconds
    acc = acc.filter((o) => now - o.ts < 1000);
    // the last value received is added to the accumulator
    acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, []),
  map((accArray) =>
    // in this last transformation we transform the array in an object which contains
    // the occurrences of each value in the last minute using the reduce method
    // of javascript Array, not to be confused with the reduce operator of rxJs
    accArray.reduce((accObj, el) => {
      if (!accObj[el.val]) {
        accObj[el.val] = 0;
      }
      accObj[el.val] = accObj[el.val] + 1;
      return accObj;
    }, {})
  )
);
```

[Here a stackblitz that demonstrate this approach.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fayz8d?file=index.ts)

Comment: OP's question specified that the solution should emit "when new value comes in to the result or when a old value pops out of the result". This doesn't satisfy the second requirement, since the only time it emits is when a new value arrives.

Comment: @backtick you are right. In order to get there we should add a `distinctUntilChanged` operator at the end of the pipeline

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, `distinctUntilChanged` means fewer emissions - but we need more emissions, not fewer. I think the only way to do it is with timers and additional events coming into the `scan`, as in my answer.

Comment: Now I get your point. Yes, if we need to notify also when "an old value pops out of the result", then your approach is the right one.

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution, this was not exactly what I was looking for. Sorry it might be due to my poor description. I do really appreciate that you tried. Thanks a lot.